# How can I send all these messages in one single line (discord.py)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
if results=='3':
      with open("somerandomwords.txt") as f:
        words = f.read().split()
      word_dict = defaultdict(list)
      for word, next_word in zip(words, words[1:]):
        word_dict[word].append(next_word)
      word="the"
      while not word.endswith('.'):
        await ctx.send(word)
        time.sleep(2)
        word = random.choice(word_dict[word])
      await ctx.send(word)
      time.sleep(50)
      print('going')
```

Each word is sent by itself. How can I make it so it forms sentences (send words on a single message on discord)?

Comment: Why are you inserting them into a dictionary?

Comment: Do you want to stick the words from somerandomwords.txt together to form a sentence?

Comment: @YannickFunk yes, thank you for clarifying. I would like some words from somerandomwords.txt to make a sentence.

Comment: Can you provide some lines of your txt file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must use `await asyncio.sleep(1)` instead of `time.sleep` because time.sleep will make your whole bot sleep not the function itself. Also no need for a dict a list will do it just fine.

I did not get the idea clearly but this is what i got.

```py
if results == '3':
    with open("somerandomwords.txt") as f:
        words = f.read().splitlines()  # a list
    random.shuffle(words)
    words_to_send = []
    for word in words:
        if word.endswith('.'):
            break
        else:
            words_to_send.append(word)
    

    await ctx.send(' '.join(words_to_send))
```